AWS codeArtifact Access token -extension
I am working with AWS CodeArtifact and need to manage access tokens for longer durations,. However, I understand that CodeArtifact has a default maximum token duration of 12 hours. Is there a way to extend this maximum duration to accommodate longer-running processes or automation tasks?
I am currently using AWS CodeArtifact to manage my software packages and repositories.
The need for longer token durations arises from specific operational requirements within our development and deployment workflows.
Any examples or detailed steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
